# Чтение нескольких данных из файла в отдельные переменные в c++

Tags: c++

Задался интересным(для меня) вопросом. А можно ли читать данные в С++ из файлов по столбцам, с помощью ifstream?
Пример:
есть файл на много(100к) строк следующего вида:

```
(int     float        float      float соответственно) 
 1       22.4000      24.1423    24.1352
 2       22.2000      24.1441    24.1367     
 3       22.0000      24.1402    24.1345
```

и т.д.
В си прочитать такой файл элементарно:

```
f = fopen("123.dat","r");
while(!feof(f))
        {
               fscanf(f,"%d %f %f %f",&a,&b,&c,&d);
               //и обрабатываем a,b,c,d как нам вздумается
        }
```

А вот с С++ возник вопрос. Были идеи насчет использования символа разделения, но не всегда понятно что там \t или пробелы. Буду рад прочитать ваши замечания. Ответы в стиле "почему бы не использовать си-вариант и не радоваться жизни" или "используй %name_lib%" библиотеку", не желательны, ибо мне интересно решить эту задачу средствами С++ и самому из спортивного интереса. 
За ранее спасибо за отклик

Comment: Если вы хотите достичь быстродействия - я вам рекомендую циклический буфер (2 или 3)*4096 байт и `sscanf` или `atof`,  или возможно даже разобрать числа даже вручную.

Comment: Не понимаю, чем `  while (cin >> x >> a >> b >> c)
    cout << x << ' ' << ' ' << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c <<'\n';` не подходит?

Comment: @Chorkov,@avp не ужели все так просто?!, даже стыдно:D спасибо за оперативный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::ifstream f("123.dat");
int a;
float b,c,d;
while( f >> a >> b >> c >> d  )
{
    //... 
}
```

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку, а если a,b,c,d являются векторами? Понадобятся ли дополнительные временные переменные?

Comment: Да, для заполнения векторов понадобятся временные переменные. (Или сторонние библиотеки.)